# What exactly is the App Pool?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

Ok so I understand how app pools work and what they do but I am wondering what exactly the app pool is, I am thinking at the moment that it is just information the metabase or some config file for use with http.sys?

I suppose another questions is, who or what spawns the worker process when a request is made?

thanks

The confused

Answer (score 0):

First you can see the application pool as the program that actually is one with your pages and runs them. So what ever you make programmatically on your pages are done using the application pool.

For example:

- user request the page a.aspx
- IIS see that is asp.net page and assign it to one app pool
- application pool see the a.aspx, check if is complied, and runs it - run your code.

Second you can see the big view, that there are many web sites lives together on one server and application pool is handle one or more web sites together.

Now, a web application can be run on one application pool, or on many application pools at the same time on the same server (this is called web garden). An in each of that you can run many threads.

Now for more details you can read [the official microsoft pages.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true)